# How to display grouped items in a select?

Tags: php, symfony

I have to display the working hours and the work position of employees grouped by their team leaders.
I can’t pass my request to retrieve the team leader and group all the corresponding employees.
I tried several methods and none of them worked. For the query on the team leaders, I would like a drop-down button to select the name of the team leader to display. As there is no team leader table, leader team field is present in the two  other tables.

erreur

> No route found for "GET /templates/poste/index.html.twig"
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
>       No route found for "GET /templates/poste/index.html.twig"
>
> ```
>   at vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:139
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent),
> ```
>
> 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
>            (vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener.php:115)
>         at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent),
>   'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
>            (vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:212)
>         at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
>            (vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:44)
>         at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   object(GetResponseEvent))
>            (vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php:143)
>         at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   object(GetResponseEvent))
>            (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:127)
>         at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
>            (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:68)
>         at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1,
>   true)
>            (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:200)
>         at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
>            (public\index.php:25)
>         at require('C:\workspace\bap01\public\index.php')
>            (vendor\symfony\web-server-bundle\Resources\router.php:42)

on git : https://github.com/Brumehilde/bap01

Type poste

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('poste', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Poste::class,
                'choice_label' => 'chef_equipe',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                    return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.nom_prenom', 'ASC');
                }
            ])
            ->add('nom_prenom')
            ->add('lundi')
            ->add('mardi')
            ->add('mercredi')
            ->add('jeudi')
            ->add('vendredi')
            ->add('samedi')
            ->add('dimanche')
            ->add('chef_equipe')
            ->add('equipe');


    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Poste::class,
            'mapped' => false,

        ]);
    }
```

TYpefind

```
/**
 * @method createView()
 */
class SearchChefFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('poste', SearchChefFormType::class, [
                'class' => Poste::class,
                'choice_label' => 'chefEquipe',
                'placeHolder' => "selectionner votre chef d'/ equipe ",
                'mapped' => false,

                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                    return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('poste')->orderBy('p.nom_prenom', 'ASC');
                }
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Poste::class,
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

Les controleurs :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="main")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/searchChefF", name="searchChef")
     */
    public function searchChef(Request $request, SearchChefFormType $searchChefFormType)
    {


        $searchChefForm = $this->createForm(SearchChefFormType::class);
        $searchChefForm->handleRequest($request);

        $chef = $searchChefForm->get('chef_equipe')->getData();

        if ($searchChefForm->isSubmitted() && $searchChefForm->isValid()) {
            $listeParChef = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Poste::class)->findByChef($chef);

            return $this->render('Poste/Find.html.twig', [
                'listeParChef' => $listeParChef,
                'nbPage' => 0,
            ]);
        }


        return $this->render('main/SearchChef.html.twig', [
            'findByChef' => $searchChefFormType->createView(),
            'nbPage' => 0,
        ]);

    }
}
```

Poste controleur :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_form", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function _form(PosteRepository $posteRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('poste/_form.html.twig', [
            'postes' => $posteRepository->FindByChef(),
        ]);


    }

    /**
     * @Route("/findByChef/{chef_equipe}", name="findByChef")
     * @ $chefEquipe
     * @return Response
     */
    public function findByChef($chefEquipe): Response
    {
        $allByChef = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Poste::class)->findByChef($chefEquipe);
        return $this->render('poste/findByChef.html.twig', ['listeParChef' => $allByChef]);

    }
```

LE REPOSITORy :

```
/**
 * @method Poste|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Poste|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Poste[]    findAll()
 * @method Poste[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PosteRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Poste::class);
    }

    /*   public function listChef($chef_equipe): Collection
       {
           $dql = ' SELECT p.chef_equipe FROM   App\Entity\Poste  p ';
           return $this->getEntityManager()
               ->createQuery($dql)
               ->setParameter('chef_equipe', $chef_equipe)
               ->getResult();
       }*/


    public function FindByChefEquipe($chef_equipe)
    {
        // Requete avec jointure pour récupérer les employé par chef d'equipe

        $dql = 'SELECT p FROM App\Entity\Poste p
                INNER JOIN App\Entity\Horaire AS h WITH p.nom_prenom = h.nom_prenom
                where p.chef_equipe= :value
                order by p.nom_prenom ';


        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter('value', $chef_equipe)
            ->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @return Poste[] Returns an array of Ad objects
     */
    public function findByChef($chefEquipe): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin('p.nom_prenom', 'h.nom_prenom')
            ->andWhere('p.chef_equipe = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $chefEquipe)
            ->orderBy('p.chef_equipe', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();


    }
```

ENTITY

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $chef_equipe;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nom_prenom = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->chef_equipe = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->equipe = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
     */
    private $equipe;

    /* public function _construct()
     {
         $this->equipe = new ArrayCollection();
     }*/

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNomPrenom(): Collection
    {
        return $this->nom_prenom;
    }

    public function setNomPrenom(string $nom_prenom): self
    {
        $this->nom_prenom = $nom_prenom;

        return $this;
    }


`` `
```

Comment: I don't see how the error `No route found for "GET /templates/poste/index.html.twig"` relates to your code. Can you search your code for `/templates/poste/index.html.twig`, probably in one of your templates?

Comment: The error is caused by your [IDE configuration](https://github.com/Brumehilde/bap01/blob/98a626ff16816ce7fb0a1389cfed0eb6114d9536/.idea/workspace.xml#L449), the generated url is wrong, it should point to the route `/poste/` and not the template file.

Comment: When i don't use debug my log error is : The options "choice_label", "class", "placeHolder", "query_builder" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr",...

Comment: Your `poste` field in `SearchChefFormType` type is of type `SearchChefFormType`. Shouldn't it be `EntityType`?

Comment: `     
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /*filtre chefEquipe*/
        $this->$builder->add('poste', EntityType::class, array(

            'class' => Poste::class,


            'query_builder' => function (PosteRepository $er) use ($options) {

                return $er->FindByChef($options['poste']);

            },

            'choice_label' => 'chef_equipe'

        ));


        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Rechercher']);`

Comment: I change for that but i have same erreur when lauch my page